# Unix Shell Script - Monitor Login Failure in specific pattern

Tags: shell, unix, monitoring, logfile

I am looking for a way to accomplish one of my requirement where I want to automate log file monitoring of "failed login attempt" with a specific pattern using Unix Shell Script.

Below is a log snippet

```
sequence_number=12345,remote_client=sapserver,2016-03-18 03:29:44:782 EDT,messageID=1002,user=jdoe@example.com,client_ip_address=10.129.220.45,client_port=10250,browser_ip_address=x.x.x.x,result_code=2,result_action=Login Failure,result_reason=Invalid Password
```

**Note**: The "result_code=2" in log file denotes a failed login.

Below is the requirement and pattern

- Monitor log file consistently (access.log)
- If a Invalid Password is noticed in the log file for the same user
  more than 50 times within a minute, trigger an email with User ID, Client IP, Browser IP, Number of failed attempts made for that run
- Watch the log and do this continuously.

Being an amateur shell script developer, i am unable to think of achieving this using shell script. Requesting for ideas / solutions.

Comment: have a look at awk - http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/06/awk-10-examples-to-group-data-in-csv-or.html   , might put you in the right direction. You can cut out columns and group by pattern - lots of examples out there that may help

Comment: Look at `fail2ban` and see if it can do what you need?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs Etan. We are not going to that extreme of blocking a user IP address when such bad password attempts are made. We as administrators want only the script to email ourself about the user and no of failed attempts made continuously within a minute or two.

Comment: Hariboo,not sure if that approach will help in realtime log monitoring and getting only the data of user who matches our monitoring criteria

Comment: You can use `fail2ban` to perform arbitrary actions, not just block ips.  Take a closer look.

Comment: Any possibilities with Shell / Perl scripting ??

Answer (score 0):

The dumb approach in shell would be to just `tail -f` your log, pipe it to `awk` to cut out the result codes and user data, and if a line denotes a failed login attempt increment the count stored in a file named by the user login (e.g. the file named `jdoe@example.com` contains `5`). But this leaves you with a problem of how to maintain that count for the desired time period only (e.g. within last minute).

Unless you really like that sort of pain, take a look at some common tools like `logwatch` which are designed specifically to do what you want.

Here are some great articles on how to setup your custom log watching and reporting with `logwatch` by examples of other custom services:

- http://alphahydrae.com/2012/08/logwatch-how-to-add-a-service/
- http://blog.bidiuk.com/2010/05/centos-custom-logwatch-script/
- http://perceptionistruth.com/2010/08/custom-logwatch-script-for-ngircd/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/571243/monitor-rsnapshots-log-file-with-logwatch

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for *probably* could be done by plugin called [logdog](https://sparrowhub.org/info/logdog):

```
$ cpanm Sparrow # install sparrow manager
$ yum install curl # you need a curl to upload sparrow index file
$ sparrow index update # get latest sparrow index 
$ sparrow plg install logdog # install logdog plugin
$ sparrow project create myhost # project is just container for runnable plugins
$ sparrow check add myhost login-check # or whatever you name it; check just a entry point to run a plugin
$ sparrow check set myhost login-check logdog # you bind a logdog plugin to your check 
$ export EDITOR=nano && sparrow check ini myhost login-check

# here comes configuration part, the hardest one
# as you have to set it precisely

[logdog]


# set path to log file

file = login.log

# this is examples of log entries
# sequence_number=12345,remote_client=sapserver,2016-03-18 03:29:44:782 EDT,messageID=1002,user=jdoe2@example.com,client_ip_address=10.129.220.45,client_port=10250,browser_ip_address=x.x.x.x,result_code=2,result_action=Login Failure,result_reason=Invalid Password


# define how to extract time chunks
# from your log entries:

# this should perl regexp:
time_pattern  = ,(\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)\s(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)

# this should be posix strftime format
# see `man strftime`
time_format   = %Y-%m-%d %T

# check logs for last 5 minutes, 10 hours, 2 days , etc ...
history = 1 months

# to proper time calculation
# need to know a timezone
timezone = UTC

# I need these lines
filter = result_code=2

# group found entries by user logins:
key_field = user=(\S+?),

# density - is optional parameter
# show only groups with entries number
# more or equal $density
density = 1
```

Given a log file:

```
$ cat login.log

sequence_number=12345,remote_client=sapserver,2016-03-18 03:29:44:782 EDT,messageID=1002,user=jdoe@example.com,client_ip_address=10.129.220.45,client_port=10250,browser_ip_address=x.x.x.x,result_code=2,result_action=Login Failure,result_reason=Invalid Password
sequence_number=12345,remote_client=sapserver,2016-03-18 03:29:44:782 EDT,messageID=1002,user=jdoe@example.com,client_ip_address=10.129.220.45,client_port=10250,browser_ip_address=x.x.x.x,result_code=2,result_action=Login Failure,result_reason=Invalid Password
sequence_number=12345,remote_client=sapserver,2016-03-18 03:29:44:782 EDT,messageID=1002,user=jdoe2@example.com,client_ip_address=10.129.220.45,client_port=10250,browser_ip_address=x.x.x.x,result_code=2,result_action=Login Failure,result_reason=Invalid Password
sequence_number=12345,remote_client=sapserver,2016-03-18 03:29:44:782 EDT,messageID=1002,user=jdoe2@example.com,client_ip_address=10.129.220.45,client_port=10250,browser_ip_address=x.x.x.x,result_code=2,result_action=Login Failure,result_reason=Invalid Password
sequence_number=12345,remote_client=sapserver,2016-03-18 03:29:44:782 EDT,messageID=1002,user=jdoe2@example.com,client_ip_address=10.129.220.45,client_port=10250,browser_ip_address=x.x.x.x,result_code=2,result_action=Login Failure,result_reason=Invalid Password
```

We will have:

```
$ sparrow check run myhost login-check

/tmp/.outthentic/22011/home/vagrant/my/logdog/story.t ..
ok 1 - stdout is already set
ok 2 - stdout saved to /tmp/.outthentic/22011/MSUYnYelwg
# history: 1 months
# filter: result_code=2
# density: 1
# group jdoe@example.com count: 2
# sequence_number=12345,remote_client=sapserver,2016-03-18 03:29:44:782 EDT,messageID=1002,user=jdoe@example.com,client_ip_address=10.129.220.45,client_port=10250,browser_ip_address=x.x.x.x,result_code=2,result_action=Login Failure,result_reason=Invalid Password
# sequence_number=12345,remote_client=sapserver,2016-03-18 03:29:44:782 EDT,messageID=1002,user=jdoe@example.com,client_ip_address=10.129.220.45,client_port=10250,browser_ip_address=x.x.x.x,result_code=2,result_action=Login Failure,result_reason=Invalid Password
# group jdoe2@example.com count: 3
# sequence_number=12345,remote_client=sapserver,2016-03-18 03:29:44:782 EDT,messageID=1002,user=jdoe2@example.com,client_ip_address=10.129.220.45,client_port=10250,browser_ip_address=x.x.x.x,result_code=2,result_action=Login Failure,result_reason=Invalid Password
# sequence_number=12345,remote_client=sapserver,2016-03-18 03:29:44:782 EDT,messageID=1002,user=jdoe2@example.com,client_ip_address=10.129.220.45,client_port=10250,browser_ip_address=x.x.x.x,result_code=2,result_action=Login Failure,result_reason=Invalid Password
# sequence_number=12345,remote_client=sapserver,2016-03-18 03:29:44:782 EDT,messageID=1002,user=jdoe2@example.com,client_ip_address=10.129.220.45,client_port=10250,browser_ip_address=x.x.x.x,result_code=2,result_action=Login Failure,result_reason=Invalid Password
ok 3 - output match /lines count: (\d+)/
ok 4 - output match /result_code=2/
1..4
ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=4,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.00 sys +  0.10 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.12 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

For you purposes ini file should be adapted:

- history = 5 minutes
- timezone = America/New_York
  ( consult this [list](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::TimeZone::Catalog) for proper values, probably this is what could be equal EST time zone )
- density = 50

Now run this plugin by cron every 5 minutes and you will probably get what you want ...

PS> DISCLOSURE - I am the author of sparrow and logdog plugin.